# Insert newline before the regex match with c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file which contains texts like below:

```
adj 1: text1 2: text2 n 1: text4 adj 1: text5 adv 1: text6 3: text7
```

I want to insert a newline(`n`) between adj, n, numbers, etc. to have the following output:

```
adj 1: text1 
2: text2 
n 1: text4 
adj 1: text5 
adv 1: text6 
3: text7
```

I have this regex: `\s+\d+|\s+((n|v|adv|adj|)\s+\d+)`

Now if I use `Regex.Replace()` it add the newline but also would remove the found matches (1, 2, n 1 and so on). Is there any way that I could insert a newline before the match without removing the match?

Comment: You will need lookarounds - zero-width assertions. If you provide a more realistic input string, there are surely people willing to help you out.

Comment: [Something close to what you need](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5bnv%5d%7cad%5bvj%5d)%3f%5cs%2b%5cd%2b%3a.*%3f(%3f%3d%24%7c(%3f%3a%5bnv%5d%7cad%5bvj%5d)%3f%5cs%2b%5cd%2b%3a)&i=adj+1%3a+text1+2%3a+text2+n+1%3a+text4+adj+1%3a+text5+adv+1%3a+text6+3%3a+text7&r=%24%26%0d%0a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment was almost correct, I decided to improve it and turn into an answer. The main point is that you have a set of keywords, that you can put into an alternation group and since you know they are followed with a space and digits that are followed with a colon, you may define this block as a separate string. Then, you may match any number of any characters up to the first occurrence of this same block.

Here is a [sample demo](http://ideone.com/L7I1Qn):

```
var s = "adj 1: text1 2: text2 n 1: text4 adj 1: text5 adv 1: text6 3: text7";
var block = @"(?:[nv]|ad[vj])?\s*\d+:";
var pat = string.Format(@"{0}.*?\s*(?={0})", block);
var result = Regex.Replace(s, pat, "$&\n");
// => adj 1: text1 
//2: text2 
//n 1: text4 
//adj 1: text5 
//adv 1: text6 
//3: text7
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:[nv]|ad[vj])?\s*\d+:` - matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `n`, `v`, `adj`, `adv`, then 0+ whitespaces and 1+ digits followed witha colon.
- `.*?\s*` - 0+ any chars but a newline up to the first 0+ whitespaces that ...
- `(?=(?:[nv]|ad[vj])?\s*\d+:)` - ...are followed with the block described above.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5Bnv%5D%7Cad%5Bvj%5D)%3F%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%3A.*%3F%5Cs*(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5Bnv%5D%7Cad%5Bvj%5D)%3F%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%3A)&i=adj%201%3A%20text1%202%3A%20text2%20n%201%3A%20text4%20adj%201%3A%20text5%20adv%201%3A%20text6%203%3A%20text7&r=%24%26%0D%0A)

Comment: Note that in .NET you never have to enclose the full pattern into a capturing group (as in the other answer) since the `$&` backreferences to the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups.

for generic prefixes, not limited to `(n|v|adv|adj)`

search for `((\w*?\s)?\d+: [\w]*?($|\s))`

for prefixes limited to `(n|v|adv|adj)`

search for `(((n|v|adv|adj)\s)?\d+: [\w]*?($|\s))`

replace with `$1\n`

https://regex101.com/r/vJ1lY1/3

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx